# Dagger MissingBinding error when injecting ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2

I have a problem with the dagger injection when I am rebuilding the project. I recently started learning dagger 2 and I encountered this error, can anyone help me? I spent a lot of time on it, your answer will help me a lot.

```kotlin
[Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.data.api.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent {
                ^
  
  Missing binding usage:
      com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.data.api.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor is injected at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.di.AppModule.provideLoggingInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
      okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor is injected at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.di.AppModule.provideOkHttp(loggingInterceptor)
      okhttp3.OkHttpClient is injected at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.di.AppModule.provideRetrofit(okHttp)
      retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder is injected at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.di.AppModule.provideApi(builder)
      com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.data.api.WeatherApi is injected at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.data.repository.WeatherRepositoryImpl(weatherApi, �)
      com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.data.repository.WeatherRepositoryImpl is injected at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.di.RepositoryModule.bindRepository(repository)
      com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.domain.repository.WeatherRepository is injected at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.ui.WeatherViewModel(repository, �)
      com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.ui.WeatherViewModel is injected at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.di.ViewModelModule.bindViewModel(viewModel)
      java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.ui.ViewModelFactory(creators)
      com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.ui.ViewModelFactory is requested at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.di.AppComponent.viewModelFactory()
  The following other entry points also depend on it:
      com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.di.AppComponent.inject(com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.MainActivity)
```

```kotlin
[Dagger/MissingBinding] android.app.Application cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent {
                ^
  
  Missing binding usage:
      android.app.Application is injected at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.data.location.LocationTrackerImpl(�, application)
      com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.data.location.LocationTrackerImpl is injected at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.di.LocationModule.bindLocationTracker(locationTracker)
      com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.domain.location.LocationTracker is injected at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.ui.WeatherViewModel(�, locationTracker)
      com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.ui.WeatherViewModel is injected at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.di.ViewModelModule.bindViewModel(viewModel)
      java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.ui.ViewModelFactory(creators)
      com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.ui.ViewModelFactory is requested at
          com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.di.AppComponent.viewModelFactory()
  It is also requested at:
      com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.di.AppModule.provideFusedLocationProviderClient(app)
  The following other entry points also depend on it:
      com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.di.AppComponent.inject(com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.MainActivity)
```

Below are my classes:

**AppComponent**

```kotlin
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, LocationModule::class, RepositoryModule::class, ViewModelModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)

    fun viewModelFactory(): ViewModelFactory
}
```

**AppModule**

```kotlin
@Module
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApi(builder: Retrofit.Builder): WeatherApi {
        return builder
            .build()
            .create(WeatherApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttp: OkHttpClient): Retrofit.Builder {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ApiConstants.API_BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttp)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttp(loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLoggingInterceptor(loggingInterceptor: LoggingInterceptor): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        return httpLoggingInterceptor
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideFusedLocationProviderClient(app: Application): FusedLocationProviderClient {
        return LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(app)
    }
}
```

**LocationModule**

```kotlin
@Module
interface LocationModule {

    @Binds
    @Singleton
    fun bindLocationTracker(locationTracker: LocationTrackerImpl): LocationTracker
}
```

**RepositoryModule**

```kotlin
@Module
interface RepositoryModule {

    @Binds
    @Singleton
    fun bindRepository(repository: WeatherRepositoryImpl): WeatherRepository
}
```

**ViewModelKey**

```kotlin
@MustBeDocumented
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

**ViewModelFactory**

```kotlin
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory @Inject
constructor(
    private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>,
            @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        var creator: Provider<out ViewModel>? = creators[modelClass]
        if (creator == null) {
            for ((key, value) in creators) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(key)) {
                    creator = value
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        if (creator == null) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass)
        }
        try {
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }

    }
}
```

**WeatherViewModel**

```kotlin
class WeatherViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: WeatherRepository,
    private val locationTracker: LocationTracker
): ViewModel() {

    private val disposables = CompositeDisposable()

    private var _state = MutableStateFlow(WeatherState())
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()

    override fun onCleared() {
        disposables.dispose()
        super.onCleared()
    }

    init {
        locationTracker.getCurrentLocation().subscribe(object : SingleObserver<Location?> {
            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                disposables.add(d)
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                _state.value.weather = State.Error(e.message.orEmpty())
            }

            override fun onSuccess(location: Location) {
                location.let {
                    repository.getWeatherData(it.latitude, it.longitude).subscribe(object : SingleObserver<State<Weather>> {
                        override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                            disposables.add(d)
                        }

                        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                            _state.value.weather = State.Error(e.message.orEmpty())
                        }

                        override fun onSuccess(weatherState: State<Weather>) {
                            _state.value.weather = weatherState
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**WeatherApp**

```kotlin
class WeatherApp: Application() {

    lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().build()
    }
}

val Context.appComponent: AppComponent
    get() = when (this) {
        is WeatherApp -> appComponent
        else -> this.applicationContext.appComponent
    }
```

**MainActivity**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var permissionLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>>

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
    private lateinit var viewModel: WeatherViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        appComponent.inject(this)

        permissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
        ) {}
        permissionLauncher.launch(arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        ))
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)[WeatherViewModel::class.java]

        when(val weatherState = viewModel.state.value.weather) {
            is State.Loading -> {
                TODO()
            }
            is State.Success -> {
                TODO()
            }
            is State.Error -> {
                TODO()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to google it but nothing there worked

Comment: For android project i strongly recommend using Hilt as "unsheathed" dagger is pure mess when it comes to managing components and especially viewmodels. Right now you have some issue with boilerplate you wouldn't even need to write with Hilt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your errors say that you are trying to use some objects which you have not provided to a dependency graph.

1. com.example.weatherforecast_rxjava_mvvm_dagger2.data.api.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.

In your AppModule you need to provide an instance of LoggingInterceptor to use it for creating HttpLoggingInterceptor. Add this function after provideLoggingInterceptor

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideLoggingInterceptorImpl(): LoggingInterceptor {
    // return LoggingInterceptor()
}
```

Or remove loggingInterceptor parameter from provideLoggingInterceptor function.

2. android.app.Application cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.

Looks like your LocationTrackerImpl is injected with an Application. Add these lines into your AppComponent and create it with the Builder, providing Application to the graph:

```
@Component.Builder
interface Builder {

    fun build(): AppComponent

    @BindsInstance
    fun app(app: Application): Builder
}
```

then, where the AppComponent is created:

```
val appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().app(this).build()
```